# Allure results don't generate on Maven build

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, allure

I'm running a Selenium test with Maven and would like to have an Allure report generated in the end. Unfortunately, I get an error message.

Maven command line:

```
clean -Dtest=TestLogs test allure:report
```

Error message:

```
[INFO] --- allure-maven:2.9:report (default-cli) @ demo ---
[INFO] Allure installation directory C:\Users\Zoe\Documents\demo\selenium_tests\demo_selenium/.allure
[INFO] Try to finding out allure 2.3.1
[INFO] Generate Allure report (report) with version 2.3.1
[INFO] Generate Allure report to C:\Users\Zoe\Documents\demo\selenium_tests\demo_selenium\target\site/allure-maven-plugin 
[ERROR] Directory C:\Users\Zoe\Documents\demo\selenium_tests\demo_selenium\target\target\allure-results not found.
[WARNING] Allure report was skipped because there is no results directories found.
```

My POM.xml:

```
<project
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.wesh.nc</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<!--<packaging>pom</packaging>-->
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>

<properties>
    <allure.version>1.5.2</allure.version>
    <allure.maven.version>2.0</allure.maven.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>${skip.selenium.tests}</skip>
                <parallel>none</parallel>
                <threadCount>1</threadCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <disableXmlReport>false</disableXmlReport>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>runSeleniumTests</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <resultsDirectory>target\allure-results</resultsDirectory>
                <inputDirectories>target\allure-results</inputDirectories>
                <outputDirectory>target\allure-report</outputDirectory>
                <reportVersion>2.3.1</reportVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.maven.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <resultsPattern>target\allure-results</resultsPattern>
                <outputDirectory>target\target-report</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gebish</groupId>
        <artifactId>geb-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gebish</groupId>
        <artifactId>geb-spock</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-groovy-2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
        <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.maven.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-commons</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-report-data</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-java-adaptor-api</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-model</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.maven.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/allure-report</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

I'm aware this POM is messy, I've been trying several things in order to make Allure work...

If someone knows what I can do to generate the allure-results directory, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed Allure listener & AspectJ configurations. Please follow the instructions from documentation page: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure1/wiki/JUnit

Also you can consider upgrading to latest Allure version. Docs for a new version can be found here https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_junit_4

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try tomorrow. I'll keep you updated and will accept your answer if manage getting my beautiful Allure logs :)

Comment: Note to future self: <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore> --> turn this to "true", because if not, the allure-report won't generate if the test fails, which is too bad because you'll especially need a report if the test is KO.

Comment: Followed the same approach but still see No plugin found for prefix 'allure' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/xx/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]                                        Sample POM - https://github.com/rkhanna1401/cucumber_selenium_grid/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

updating Aspect to the latest version solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I spend too much time in the same problem and after long conversation with chatGPT i found below issue which was not creating allure-results folder

I already had below configs in my pom.xml but it was not generating allure-results.

Configuration under maven-surefire plugin inside build tag

```
` <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <allure.results.directory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                     <dependency>
                         <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>`
```

> other Dependencies are as below which were present

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-attachments</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-java-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.0</version> <!-- Replace with the desired version -->


 </dependency>



 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng-version}</version>
    </dependency
```

but this was not solving the problem in my testNG + Maven + Selenium + Java + Allure Setup . On Researching too many blogs , links , ChatGPT i found that i was missing 2 important things. allureTestNG listener in TestNG.xml

```
  <suite name="automation">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="io.qameta.allure.testng.AllureTestNg"/>
    </listeners>
```

allure-maven plug

```
`   <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportVersion>2.14.0</reportVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

`

On running `mvn clean test` now , my allure-results are getting generated in desired location mentioned in your pom.xml and i can simply write another command

```
allure generate target/allure-results
allure open
```

and Bingo !!

beautiful Allure :) is there

[image]

If you will not use the listener and other plugins i mentioned above  allure-results folder will not be generated

you will try to generate allure-report folder with below command

```
allure generate target/surefire-reports 
allure open
```

but the report which will now open will be little less descriptive and will not contains many important aspects like @step details . Sample is as below
see the difference .

[image]

Hope that helps !!