# Maven test not creating allure results

Tags: maven, testng, allure

I have a setup that's using TestNG and Allure reports, which works fine when I run the test from IntelliJ. I had a look at the run configuration and all it does is a build before executing the test. That process then creates the allure results in the allure-results folder.

I had a look at this question ([Allure results don't generate on Maven build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685835/allure-results-dont-generate-on-maven-build)), but that didn't solve the problem for me.

Is there something missing from my pom file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Groovy_Practice</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <groovy.version>2.5.8</groovy.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.testng.AllureTestListener</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
                    <version>${groovy.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <!-- This goal adds Groovy test sources to the project's test sources. -->
                        <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                        <goal>compileTests</goal> <!-- Compiles tests -->
                        <!-- generates stubs in target/generated-sources/groovy-stubs/test, only needed when
                             compiling Java code that depends on Groovy code -->
                        <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                        <goal>removeTestStubs</goal> <!-- remove generated stubs from sources list -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ru.yandex.qatools.allure/allure-testng-adaptor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was in the gmaven-plugin part of the pom. I updated that and also changed my project to only have groovy classes (no java classes). My working pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>Groovy_Practice</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <groovy.version>2.5.8</groovy.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
        <configuration>
          <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
          <argLine>
            -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
          </argLine>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <resultsDirectory>allure-results</resultsDirectory>
          <inputDirectories>allure-results</inputDirectories>
          <outputDirectory>allure-report</outputDirectory>
          <reportVersion>2.3.1</reportVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>addSources</goal>
              <goal>addTestSources</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>compileTests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
      <version>${groovy.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.14.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-testng -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
      <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
      <version>1.27</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```